# How read specific lists in Json

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

I'm using google direction api to get json response and then I save it. I want to accesses the Html instructions for all the 23 steps that are returned but don't know how to save only instruction in a file or variable so they are in order

directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["steps"][0]["html_instructions"]

Comment: it would be usful to share example of your json as well as your [mcve]